# Remote shell on Ubuntu-eclipse displays too many lines

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, eclipse, remote-access

I am using Ubuntu on my Windows laptop to cross-compile and remote-debug some stuff on my raspberry pi 2. I'm connected over a USB-to-ethernet adapter.

When I ssh-connect over the normal terminal in Ubuntu I can normally navigate on the pi, but when I use the "Remote shell"-tab inside eclipse it looks like I send commands multiple times when I just hit the enter-key once. Actually the command is just sent once like it is supposed to be, but after that 2 empty lines appear as if I hit the enter-key 2 times, which I did not.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The double command prompt is due to the way how the remote current directory is queried and displayed in an RSE-compatible prompt.

Please check this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=162857).